# Unable to uninstall Ubuntu from "uninstall-wubi.exe"

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, wubi, uninstall

I tried to uninstall ubuntu with `easybcd` and forgot to uninstall it from `uninstall-wubi.exe`. When I tried to unintsall it from that file, got an error:

[image]

I have Windows 64bit installed as well and I installed Ubuntu via Wubi.

> log: never mind, it's too long (478997 letters)

Comment: If Ubuntu is not on your boot partition, can't you just delete Ubuntu's partitions?

Comment: Just delete the wubi folder...

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/925779 (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation for manual instructions)

Comment: You can paste a log of virtually unlimited size at http://paste.ubuntu.com. IF you do so, remember to give a link.

Answer (score 1):

Use just plain Wubi, you can uninstall with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed with the Wubi installer (you ran the installer within Windows), then you can uninstall the installation by locating 'Ubuntu' in the Uninstall Programs list in the Windows Control Panel.